# How to fetch a corresponding column with a particular value in another column?

Tags: r

Say, I have a dataframe with three columns:

```
Year     Sales     Income
1         100       30
2         200       20
3         NA        10
4         300       50
5         NA       -20
```

I want to get all the 'Year' that has a particular value in 'Sales', ignoring other columns. For example, if I ask for NA, I should get:

```
Year    Sales
3       NA
5       NA
```

Please note there is no Income in the above data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `base R` with `subset`

```
subset(df, is.na(Sales), select = c('Year', 'Sales'))
#  Year Sales
#3    3    NA
#5    5    NA
```

#### data

```
df <-structure(list(Year = 1:5, Sales = c(100L, 200L, NA, 300L, NA
), Income = c(30L, 20L, 10L, 50L, -20L)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `base R`. In a dataframe you can index by rows (left to `,`) and by columns (right to `,`) inside the brackets. So, you can specify the conditions, in this case `NA` in `Sales` and then select the variables like `Year` and `Sales`. Here the code:

```
#Code
df[is.na(df$Sales),c('Year','Sales')]
```

Output:

```
  Year Sales
3    3    NA
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Year = 1:4, Sales = c(100L, 200L, NA, 300L), Income = c(30L, 
20L, 10L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the %in% subsetting which has to be declared before. I usually use these in ggplot directly. hope they work independently too. For example:

```
col11 <- c("c11", "c12")
typecol2 <- c("c22", "c24")
data_new <- subset(data old, (col1 %in% col11) & (col2 %in% typecol2))
```